# Initializing default values of one class to another c++

Tags: c++

I have two classes. One has some private members that have default values.

The second class has a private member `obj` that is the object of the first class, and some other numbers.

I don't know how to initialize the `obj` object to his defaults in the constructor of the second class.

```
class One{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    One(int aa=1, int bb=2, int cc=3):a(aa), b(bb), c(cc){}
};

class two{
private:
    One obj;
    int d;
public:
    two(obj=?, d=10){}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the data type. You can simply create a new object as default like this:

```
class two{
private:
    One obj;
    int d;
public:
    two(One object=One(), int dd=10): obj(object), d(dd){}
};
```